# What do I need to calculate UV intensity?

Tags: experimental-physics

I have a mineralogical UV lamp that I want to use for some research, I only know it's wavelengths. To calculate the µJ/cm3, what else is needed?
Distance, time, wattage? Is the value I'm looking for, in µJ/cm3 the intensity? 
Is intensity something that needs to also be calculated based on time and distance, or is it like luminescence and I could get that info from the manufacturer?
Is intensity the same as 'exposure'? as in, the amount of UV that the test subject is being exposed to?

Comment: Would [electronics.se] SE be a better home for your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you want to calculate $\mu J/cm^3$, that is the energy density, not the intensity. Intensity is the number of photons emitted/incident per unit time depending on what surface you want to calculate the intensity.

You have the wavelength, you can compute the energy of each photon using the formula $$E = \frac{h c}{\lambda}.$$ The distance from the source to say the screen is required in case it is not a coherent source like a laser, which I am guessing it is not. Finally, you need to know things like how much dissipation in energy there is and the wattage. Once you have all these things, it is straightforward to calculate the quantities you want. The wattage is the amount of energy the lamp produces per unit time. Let us take it to be joules per second. So in 1 s, the lamp produces $p$ joules. Let the efficiency of your entire lamp + circuitry set up be $D$%. So the net energy per second that is output is $$\frac{Dp}{100}.$$ The number of photons that are emitted per second (Which is the original intensity of the lamp) is $$N_0 = \frac{Dp \lambda}{100 h c}.$$ To calculate the energy density, you need to determine how far away from the lamp you want to do so. Once you have this, all you need to do is integrate the quantity $$I  = \frac{3 N_0}{4\pi}\int_{x = r}^{x = r+1} \frac{dx}{x^2}. $$ This quantity $I$ is the number density, i.e., the number of photons contained in $1\,\text{cm}^3$ of volume at a distance $r$ away from the source. Multiply this with the energy $E$ of the photon and divide by $10^{-6}$, you have the answer that you are looking for.

PS: I might have been very loose with my units, make sure all your energy/length/time scales are in consistent units.